# Presenting the UIDatePicker like in iOS Calendar app

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uidatepicker

I've managed to get the UIDatePicker to a UITableView and it works fine, shows and hides when you click on other cells.  But there are two problems.

Since I added it to the view, I can't use ScrollPositionMiddle since the UIDatePicker will cover it up.
The other problem is that I can't scroll down to my other cells 'cause it's blocking it from view.  Anyone have any better implementations on how to add the UIDatePicker to a UITableView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the only step you're missing is to set the contentInsets of the table view to the size of the overlap. That should fix the rest of your problems.